# What is JUnit5 Platform Launcher exactly?

Tags: maven, junit5

JUnit 5 is modular.

I understand that everything is based on *Platform Module* (`junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar`):

*Jupiter Module* (*API + engine parts*: `junit-jupiter-engine-5.3.2.jar` + `junit-jupiter-api-5.3.2.jar`) and

*Vintage Module* (*API + engine parts*: `junit-vintage-engine-5.3.2.jar` + `junit-4.12.jar` and `hamcrest-core-1.3.jar`) both use Platform Module as the basic one.

But **what is the Platform Launcher and when is it needed?**

When and why may I need it and how to add it to `pom.xml`?

[image: Junit]
(picture is courtesy of this [link](https://blog.codefx.org/design/architecture/junit-5-architecture-jupiter/))

Adding Jupiter (for JUnit 5 tests only) and Vintage (for Junit4/Junit3 compatibility - to run legacy JUnit4 tests from JUnit5) to pom.xml is like this (just for future reference):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Vintage Module to run JUnit4 from JUnit 5 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I would recommend to use the most recent version which 5.4.0...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You only need the launcher when you want to start a JUnit platform run programmatically, i.e. outside an IDE, build tool or console runner.

In other words: the launcher is the API being used by IDEs and build tools.

Comment: is this plateforme launcher different from the junit-platform-console ? if yes when do we need the junit-platform-console ?

Comment: @soung Launcher is a Java API, console is a command line tool.